# Filename in file browser - Bootstrap 4

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

The file browser in Boostrap 4 is missing the file name. It just say Choose file...
I made a javascript solution for it. Is there any better way to solve it?

HTML

```
<label class="file">
    <input type="file" id="file1" >
    <span class="file-custom" data-content="Choose file..."></span>
</label>
```

jQuery

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function(){
    var fieldVal = $(this).val();
    if (fieldVal != undefined || fieldVal != "") {   
        $(this).next(".file-custom").attr('data-content', fieldVal);
    }
});
```

CSS

```
.file-custom:after {
    content: attr(data-content);
}
```

The only difference is that you have to add data-content to the span. On the other hand it makes it easier to change language.

Link to Bootstraps file browser:
http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/forms/#file-browser

Comment: This is not actually a problem with Bootstrap itself (4 is also nowhere near production ready, so you shouldn't really be asking for help here about it). Your solution (editing the CSS content) is probably the cleanest way to do it, honestly.

Comment: I know version 4 it's not ready yet. But we still use it, so this might be a temporary solution.... Time will tell

Comment: Thanks, this saved me some time. I'm using your solution slightly modified.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like Bootstrap is now leaning towards not adding a JS solution for this and instead likely will be including something like your script in the documentation as a suggested implementation, based on mdo's comments here, where there is also a much more complete solution:
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/20813

I have updated your simple code for Bootstrap 4 Alpha 6.

jQuery

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function () {
  var fieldVal = $(this).val();
  if (fieldVal != undefined || fieldVal != "") {
    $(this).next(".custom-file-control").attr('data-content', fieldVal);
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.custom-file-control:after {
    content: attr(data-content) !important;
}
```

---

*Edit:*

The above will show something like `C:\\fakepath...` in the styled input, we can also get *only the file name itself* to show, using `event.target.files[0].name`:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function (event) {
  var fieldVal = event.target.files[0].name;
  if (fieldVal != undefined || fieldVal != "") {
    $(this).next(".custom-file-control").attr('data-content', fieldVal);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Following up on Joey's answer, for Bootstrap 4 public release you would now use this JS and no CSS:

```
$("input[type=file]").change(function () {
    var fieldVal = $(this).val();
    if (fieldVal != undefined || fieldVal != "") {
        $(this).next(".custom-file-label").text(fieldVal);
    }
});
```